# How does CKEditor protects against CSRF?

Tags: cookies, ckeditor, csrf-protection

When using the CKEditor (4.9.1), you may notice that a `ckCsrfToken` cookie is being set. From the [release notes](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/release/CKEditor-4.5.6), this seems to be used as a CSRF protection when uploading files.

I couldn't find any documentation on how the CKEditor protects against CSRF attacks. Is CKEditor implementing the [Double Submit Cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) strategy?

The reason I'm asking is that our client wants an explanation on the purpose of this cookie, which is not HTTP only.

Any link to a reference documentation or source code would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: evidences show that CKEditor allows any third party File Uploader to protect itself against CSRF attacks by using the Double Submit Cookie strategy.**

Now for the full story: looking at the source code, it appears that the CKEditor [generates a CSRF token on demand](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/tools.js#L1453) and stores it in a cookie (which cannot be HTTP only as it's set on client side):

```
/**
 * Returns the CSRF token value. The value is a hash stored in `document.cookie`
 * under the `ckCsrfToken` key. The CSRF token can be used to secure the communication
 * between the web browser and the server, i.e. for the file upload feature in the editor.
 *
 * @since 4.5.6
 * @returns {String}
 */
getCsrfToken: function() {
    var token = CKEDITOR.tools.getCookie( TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME );

    if ( !token || token.length != TOKEN_LENGTH ) {
        token = generateToken( TOKEN_LENGTH );
        CKEDITOR.tools.setCookie( TOKEN_COOKIE_NAME, token );
    }

    return token;
}
```

Then both the [File Tools](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/filetools) and the [File Browser](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/filebrowser) plugins submit that token when calling the upload URL, as seen [in the `fileUploadRequest` handler](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/filetools/plugin.js#L67):

```
// Append token preventing CSRF attacks.
$formData.append( 'ckCsrfToken', CKEDITOR.tools.getCsrfToken() );
```

and [in the `appendToken` method](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/filebrowser/plugin.js#L192):

```
tokenElement.setAttribute( 'value', CKEDITOR.tools.getCsrfToken() );
```

The CKEditor control itself does not ship with a "file uploader". It is therefore the responsibility of the developer integrating the CKEditor in his/her product to use this token to implement CSRF protection.

[CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/ckfinder/) --the paid "file uploader" that integrates with CKEditor-- makes use of the CSRF token and, [looking at the release notes](https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKFinder-3.2-for-PHP-Released/), it seems that this token was added for the CKFinder:

> Note for CKEditor users: In order to upload files directly inside CKEditor with updated CKFinder (with CSRF protection enabled), CKEditor should also be updated to the latest stable version ([CKEditor 4.5.6](https://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5.6-Released/) released on 9th Dec, 2016).

Finally, the [source code of CKFinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/#ckfinder) makes it clear that the CSRF protection is implemented using the [Double Submit Cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) strategy (see DoubleSubmitCookieTokenValidator.php):

```
/**
 * DoubleSubmitCookieTokenValidator constructor.
 *
 * @param string $tokenParamName
 * @param string $tokenCookieName
 * @param int    $minTokenLength
 */
public function __construct($tokenParamName = 'ckCsrfToken', $tokenCookieName = 'ckCsrfToken', $minTokenLength = 32)
{
    $this->tokenParamName = $tokenParamName;
    $this->tokenCookieName = $tokenCookieName;
    $this->minTokenLength = $minTokenLength;
}

/**
 * Checks if the request contains a valid CSRF token.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return bool `true` if the token is valid, `false` otherwise.
 */
public function validate(Request $request)
{
    $paramToken = trim((string) $request->get($this->tokenParamName));
    $cookieToken = trim((string) $request->cookies->get($this->tokenCookieName));

    if (strlen($paramToken) >= $this->minTokenLength && strlen($cookieToken) >= $this->minTokenLength) {
        return $paramToken === $cookieToken;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice research Gyum Fox. As a member of the CKEditor & CKFinder projects I confirm all you have written above.